# Having problems with font, background and footer

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, fonts, background-image

I'm kind of new to htlm/css thing, I'm making my first site and I just can't figure out some stuff.

First of I work in dreaweaver... In dreamweaver everything looks ok but when I preview I'm missing the right font(I have the font otf. in my main folder), background and somehow I get a unwanted link in my footer.

Thank you for all your anwsers in advance.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div>
<li>

<a href="projects.html"</a>
<img src="lg.png" width="600" height="593" alt=""/>

</li>
<div>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>mtp</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>


<footer >Coypright 2016 Matic Toni</footer>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
div {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
body {
background-image: url(background.jpg);
background-sizce: cover;
}

footer {
font-family:"Proxima Nova ScOsf ExCn Rg"
text-align: center;
clear: both;
background-color: #000000;
bottom: 100px;
color: #BDBDBD;
font-size: x-small;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Comment: You have `<a href="projects.html"</a>` in your HTML. You should close that `<a>` tag

Comment: Your HTML is all kinds of invalid. I'd be surprised if dreamweaver generated that without any warnings. Run it through a validator.

Comment: Furthermore, all your html is inside the `<head>`. It NEEDS to be in the `<body>`

Comment: I changed the a tag and the div tag... but all my problems still remain

Comment: i relocated the footer and now its not centered and the css can't align it...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your opening and closing tags are complete. There is an offending line here:

```
<a href="projects.html"</a>
<img src="lg.png" width="600" height="593" alt=""/>
```

The fix is as follows:

```
<a href="projects.html">
    <img src="lg.png" width="600" height="593" alt=""/>
</a>
```

That being said, your html is rather malformed. Make sure you are matching all opening and closing tags. The elements should form a tree like structure.

[Here is a codepen with the html fixed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKLjML).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>mtp</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="projects.html">
          <img src="lg.png" width="600" height="593" alt="" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>Coypright 2016 Matic Toni</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A good way to make sure your HTML is valid, is by indenting lines to the appropriate level. You will notice in the codepen how the HTML is indented to indicate the elements position in the DOM tree.

Comment: I still don't have the font or the background... the good thing is that I don't have the link in my footer but now I can't center the text in the footer...

Comment: Regarding the font, you will need to set up a `@fontface`, [here is some more documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

Comment: Also, you need to be very careful with spelling everything correctly when programming HTML, CSS or any programming language. There are a number of errors with your CSS, like missing semi-colons and mispelling attributes.

Comment: what about the background? should a add something in the css?

Comment: + i added to the bottom of my css @font-face { font-family: "Proxima Nova ScOsf ExCn Rg"
             src: url("Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova ScOsf Extra Condensed Regular") format("opentype")
}
           it didn't cange anything

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set the background to an image? You will need to make sure that the url for the image is correct. This url is relative to the location of the stylesheet.

Comment: yes, it is in my main folder but when previewed online it's not there

Comment: I would recommend opening up Chrome Dev Tools (or similar) and use that to try and find out why it is not loading. Check the console and that should give you some information